# CoreData ManagedObjectContext Recursive Save Error

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Some users of mine are encountering a CoreData error when performing a save. I haven't been able to find any information online about this error or how to symbolicate the stack trace.

The error message is `attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted, stack trace`, with the full error message below.

Doe anyone have any hints or ideas on how to figure out what is going wrong?

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=132001 "(null)" UserInfo={message=attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted, stack trace=(
0   CoreData                            0x0000000188cbe70c  + 164
1   Primetime                           0x0000000100077ea4 Primetime + 130724
2   Primetime                           0x00000001000ae988 Primetime + 354696
3   Primetime                           0x0000000100081674 Primetime + 169588
4   Primetime                           0x00000001000802ac Primetime + 164524
5   CoreData                            0x0000000188d8bbd4  + 4568
6   CoreData                            0x0000000188d8a9ec  + 124
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001869ac24c  + 20
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001869ab950  + 400
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001869ab6cc  + 60
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186a187bc  + 1504
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001868ef32c _CFXNotificationPost + 376
12  Foundation                          0x000000018738296c  + 68
13  CoreData                            0x0000000188cc16e8  + 724
14  CoreData                            0x0000000188d43ca4  + 1336
15  CoreData                            0x0000000188cbfd04  + 2116
16  CoreData                            0x0000000188cbe808  + 416
17  Primetime                           0x0000000100077ea4 Primetime + 130724
18  Primetime                           0x0000000100089968 Primetime + 203112
19  Primetime                           0x00000001001d47c0 Primetime + 1558464
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000186459058  + 24
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000186459018  + 16
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018645dbcc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001869bfc48  + 12
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001869bd834  + 1660
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001868ed764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 292
26  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001882f0198 GSEventRunModal + 180
27  UIKit                               0x000000018c8668d0  + 664
28  UIKit                               0x000000018c86163c UIApplicationMain + 208
29  Primetime                           0x00000001000ada1c Primetime + 350748
30  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001864905b8  + 4
```

Comment: Any chance that you're calling `save:` from code that runs when `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` is posted?

Comment: I am not using that notification, though I am using `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`. I just checked the documentation for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` and it says it is not safe to call `save` yet. I did find some spots in my code where a save could be triggered from `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`. I will continue to dig in to it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm only getting this in iOS10 beta 4 not happening in iOS 9.3.3 and unable to find a solution. Have your users upgraded?

Comment: I just have the error messages being logged, not the os version, so I don't know. It is possible, as it's only a small percentage of the users seeing it.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem with the Xcode8/ios10. The problem was due to a call to save core data context inside the following method.

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self methodCallingSaveContext];
}
```

The

```
methodCallingSaveContext
```

calls the save core data context.
In order to break the recursive call I rewrote the method in the following way:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [self methodCallingSaveContext];
         });
}
```

Now everything is working again.